# How to convert a 3d RGB NumPy array to float without changing the image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save an image that is in RGB pixel form. For whatever reason, when I call `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`, the image is displayed properly.

However, when I call `matplotlib.pyplot.imsave`, I get an error that the array has to be in `float`. When I decided to change all the values to `float`, the image is completely modified. It makes no sense to me.

```
def display_image(pixels, name=""):
    if name:
        plt.imsave(name, array)
    plt.imshow(array)

pixels = im.getdata()
pixelMap = im.load()
npImage = np.array(pixels).reshape(671, 450, 3)
display_image(npImage) ## great!

# things that I tried
display_image(npImage, "image.jpg") ## error, must be floats.

# changes the images
pixels = list(pixels) ## pixels var originally imagecore class
for index in range(len(pixels)):
    pixels[index] = (float(pixels[index][0]), float(pixels[index][1]), float(pixels[index][2]))
display_image(npImage, "monaLisa.jpg") ## works but incorrect image
```

Comment: if my question is bad, I would appreciate a reason why. To me, it seems specific and shows an attempts. I guess I am still learning how to ask a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I'll give an answer to your actual question, a few words regarding your comment, and why you might got a downvote on your question. Your code is no [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and also not working as is.

You're missing all the necessary imports:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

One of your method parameters is wrong:

```py
def display_image(pixels, name=""):    #  <-- I assume, pixels should be array here.
    if name:
        plt.imsave(name, array)
    plt.imshow(array)
    plt.show()                         #  <-- Without, there's no actual output.
```

What's `im`? Most likely, that's some PIL image. Also, you hard-coded some values, without providing the corresponding image.

```py
im = Image.open('someImage.jpg')                   #  <-- Need to load some image at all.
pixels = im.getdata()
pixelMap = im.load()
npImage = np.array(pixels).reshape(671, 450, 3)    #  <-- That only works for images with the specific size
display_image(npImage) ## great!
```

In the last test case, you're not updating `npImage`:

```py
pixels = list(pixels) ## pixels var originally imagecore class
for index in range(len(pixels)):
    pixels[index] = (float(pixels[index][0]), float(pixels[index][1]), float(pixels[index][2]))

#  <-- You updated pixels, but not npImage

display_image(npImage, "monaLisa.jpg")
```

Only after fixing all these issues, one comes to the actual error, you're talking about in your question!

---

Now, to your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...].py", line 18, in <module>
    display_image(npImage, "image.jpg") ## error, must be floats.
  [...]
ValueError: Image RGB array must be uint8 or floating point; found int32
```

Your `npImage` is of type `int32`, but `plt.imsave` expects `uint8` (values `0 ... 255)`or `float` (values `0.0 ... 1.0`) for writing.

So, let's enforce `uint8`:

```py
npImage = np.array(pixels, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(..., 3)
```

After adding the necessary update of `npImage` as mentioned above

```py
pixels = list(pixels) ## pixels var originally imagecore class
for index in range(len(pixels)):
    pixels[index] = (float(pixels[index][0]), float(pixels[index][1]), float(pixels[index][2]))
npImage = np.array(pixels).reshape(..., 3)                              #  <-- This line
display_image(npImage, "monaLisa.jpg") ## works but incorrect image
```

the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...].py", line 25, in <module>
    display_image(npImage, "monaLisa.jpg") ## works but incorrect image
  [...]
ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.
```

You haven't scaled your `float` values to `0.0 ... 1.0`. So, we just divide by `255`:

```py
npImage = np.array(pixels).reshape(..., 3) / 255
```

I couldn't reproduce your "completely modified image" (due to possibly missing code fragments), but most likely this was also due to the unscaled `float` values, and you possibly saw clipping. (Was the image almost white?)

Hope that helps!